# How to Ensure TypeScript Type-Checking in a Hardhat Project Before Execution?

Tags: hardhat, typescript

I'm working on a Hardhat project with TypeScript enabled. Currently, I can run my TypeScript scripts even if there are type errors, presumably due to the use of `ts-node`. I would like to enforce type correctness before my scripts actually execute. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In Hardhat projects that utilize TypeScript, by default, TypeScript files are transpiled on-the-fly to JavaScript using `ts-node` and then executed. This means even if there are type errors, the scripts might still run. However, for those wanting to ensure strict type correctness before any script or task execution, Hardhat offers a straightforward solution.

`hardhat` provides the `--typecheck` flag as detailed in the [official Hardhat documentation](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/typescript#type-checking-your-project). When you append this flag to your Hardhat commands, the system will enforce type-checking and won't proceed with the execution if type errors are present.

For instance, running:

```bash
npx hardhat test
```

will execute your tests even if there's a TypeScript compilation error. However, if you run:

```bash
npx hardhat test --typecheck
```

hardhat via `ts-node` will check for TypeScript errors first, and if any are detected, it will halt execution and report the errors.